# SQL Query Stuck in Infintite Loop

Tags: sql, infinite-loop

I'm running a pretty simple SQL query on my database, and it seems to be returning the same record over and over, creating an infinite loop. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I don't see it. Here's the query:

```
select s.customer as 'Customer',
    s.store as 'Store',
    s.item as 'Item',
    d.dlvry_dt as 'Delivery',
    i.item_description as 'Description',
    mj.major_class_description as 'Major Description',
    s.last_physical_inventory_dt as 'Last Physical Date',
    s.qty_physical as 'Physical Qty',
    s.avg_unit_cost as 'Unit Cost',
    [qty_physical] * [avg_unit_cost] as Value
from database.DELIVERY d,
    database.STORE_INVENTORY s,
    database.ITEM_MASTER i,
    database.MINOR_ITEM_CLASS mi,
    database.MAJOR_ITEM_CLASS mj,
    database.STORE_INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENT sa
where sa.store = s.store
    and s.last_physical_inventory_dt between '6/29/2011' and '7/2/2011'
    and s.customer = '20001'
    and s.last_physical_inventory_dt is not null
```

There is one record that falls on 7/1/2011 and it repeats it forever until I cancel the query.

Any help on preventing this?

Comment: Please help us help you. Format your code so it's not a major task to decipher it.

Comment: Rewrite the query using ANSI syntax and the issue will become apparent, one of the many reasons I promote it.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used SQL in a while, I thought this was the basic syntax. I'll look up a better format and repost. Thanks for the responses

Comment: Hint: you'll be using `JOIN` and `ON` keywords.

Comment: Also, SQL does not loop unless you are using a cursor or while (and you almost never want to do that). You are actually seeing a very large set.

Comment: You should go **all the way** and replace this `from argus.STORE_INVENTORY s, argus.STORE_INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENT sa` ... `where sa.store = s.store ` with a simple `from argus.STORE_INVENTORY s INNER JOIN argus.STORE_INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENT sa ON s.store = sa.store`, too !

Comment: Regarding the error "s.item" not found, this is because the second table source in your FROM clause is sa join i on (s.item=i.item). In this table source, there is no table "s". Perhaps this is not the join you want, or perhaps you want FROM (s cross join sa) join i on (s.item = i.item). (I'm giving just the aliases here in the hope that makes what I'm saying a bit clearer - obviously you have to name the tables in your actual query.)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, because the answers on this question all related to your previous code (and were therefore confusing). Please only edit questions to clarify. If you have a new question ask a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're joining all these tables: `database.DELIVERY`, `database.ITEM_MASTER`, `database.MINOR_ITEM_CLASS`, and `database.MAJOR_ITEM_CLASS` - without specifying *how* to join them.  You need to specify how these tables are joined with the rest.

**If each of these tables has ONLY 100 rows, it will give you 100 * 100 * 100 * 100 rows (100 million) minimum rows! (see [Cartesian Join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Cartesian_join))**

Comment: Its not a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, op has multiple `CROSS JOIN`s, wich is much much worse

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that the WHERE clause would likely bring this number down significantly (and to be fair there *is* one clause joining two of the tables), but the essence is correct.

Comment: @RedFilter: if you look at the where clause, none of the tables I've listed are mentioned...so it wouldn't bring it down at all!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks guys! I just added the joins/fixed the formatting. Now I'm working on fixing that error, but I think I'm on the right track. Apparently I can't use the s.item syntax again, I'll try using 'Item' as I named it in the Select

Answer (score 0):

You haven't joined all your tables.  For example, tables MINOR_ITEM_CLASS, database.MAJOR_ITEM_CLASS & database.ITEM_MASTER are missing joins.  Missing joins causes the query engine to do a Cartesian join on the tables not explicitly joined.  So you don't have an endless loop, you just many duplicate copies of the same record.  Eventually your query will stop.

Add the appropriate joins for those tables & let  us how it goes.  You could also try adding the DISTINCT key word.